# Need help understanding an event being assigned "delegate { }"

Tags: c#

While looking at an UWP example app, I came across this [code](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-appsample-trafficapp/blob/master/LocationHelper/BindableBase.cs). What I don't understand and can't seem to find in google is line 40:

```
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
```

Says in the comments that it is a multicast event. What does assigning `delegate { }` do? Does it have anything to do with the comment saying the event is multicast?

Answer (score 3):

> What does assigning `delegate { }` do?

That is simply adding an anonymous function to the event, with an empty body. Since C#3, one would generally use a lambda expression instead:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (s, e) => { };
```

However, lambda expressions require each parameter to be elicited, whereas using `delegate` does not. So if you don't need to use the arguments, then `delegate` may be more concise.

Microsoft highlight this as the single remaining use case of the `delegate` syntax for defining an anonymous function:

> When you use the delegate operator, you might omit the parameter list. If you do that, the created anonymous method can be converted to a delegate type with any list of parameters. That's the only functionality of anonymous methods that is not supported by lambda expressions. In all other cases, a lambda expression is a preferred way to write inline code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/delegate-operator

> Does it have anything to do with the comment saying the event is multicast?

No; multicast means that you can add more than one handling function to the event, and when the event is raised, each one is invoked.

For example:

```
class Example
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaiseEvent()
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(default, default);
    }
}

var example = new Example();

// Use the += operator to add a new handler (rather than = which overwrites)
example += delegate { Console.Writeline("Handler 1"); };
example += delegate { Console.Writeline("Handler 2"); };

example.RaiseEvent();

// Output:
// Handler 1
// Handler 2
```

---

> Follow up question: What is the purpose of assigning an anonymous function to the event?

If no handler has been added, invoking the event can cause a `NullReferenceException`, so assigning an empty handler could remove the necessity to handle null.

So the event can be raised like this:

```
PropertyChanged.Invoke(default, default);
```

Or this:

```
PropertyChanged(default, default);
```

Rather than this:

```
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(default, default);
```

Comment: The difference being that your lambda expression version doesn't compile, because you have to specify the right number of parameters. A parameterless anonymous method will work regardless of parameters (assuming none of them are `out` parameters, of course.)

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was an anonymous function too but wasn't sure cause I was used to seeing the lambda expression syntax. Follow up question: What is the purpose of assigning an anonymous function to the event?

Comment: @johnjeruelTiongco - I would guess if you look elsewhere where the event is invoked they've elided null checks because they've guaranteed it's never null.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an empty delegate, but the compiler will derive delegates from [MulticastDelegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.multicastdelegate?view=net-6.0#remarks). So all delegates in C# are multicast.

```
Action d = delegate { };
// True
Console.WriteLine(d.GetType().BaseType == typeof(MulticastDelegate));
```

Comment: Follow up question: What's the purpose of assigning an empty delegate to an event?

Comment: @johnjeruelTiongco not having to check for `null` on the event when invoking (an event is `null` if there's no delegate assigned to, and you get an exception if you try to do `myEvent.Invoke()` without checking for null). It's always assigned something.

Myself, I prefer to do `myEvent?.Invoke()` and not assign an empty delegate, but that's the main reason

Comment: @johnjeruelTiongco To avoid null check. `delegate { }` is an old school syntax, so the code shall be written before the null-conditional operator (`?.Invoke`) was invented,

Comment: Thanks. I checked the method that raises the event and it doesn't use the null-conditional operators.